# PandoraBot API: Invalid botname

Tags: pandorabots

I got the following error:

```
{ "status": "error", "message": "Invalid botname"}
```

When I am using the Pandorabot CLI. My bot name and my setting name are the same, so do you have any idea on where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error today, when I used upper case in the name. Try use only lower case.